# Change directory without using 'cd'

Tags: shell-script, file-copy, working-directory

I have a list of files with their paths in a text file. And I want to copy these files, mentioned in list, to another directory with their parent folders tree. Also my shell-script to copy these files is in the same directory as this text-file.

Now I have put this text file inside a directory and I want to copy files as listed in the text file from the parent folder of the current directory of text file.

List of files is like below:

```
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location/Edit.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location/Grid.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location/Import.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location/Edit/Form.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location/Edit/Import.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location/Edit/Tabs.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location/Edit/Tab/Form.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Location/Edit/Tab/Import.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/controllers/IndexController.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/controllers/LocationController.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/LocationController.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/etc/adminhtml.xml
../app/code/community/Company/Module/etc/config.xml
../app/code/community/Company/Module/etc/system.xml
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Helper/Data.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/sql/pmodule_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/Defaultcountry.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/Location.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/Observer.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/System/Config/Source/Radiuses.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/System/Config/Source/RadiusUnits.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/Mysql4/Location.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/Mysql4/Location/Collection.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/Radiuses.php
../app/code/community/Company/Module/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source/RadiusUnits.php
../app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/pmodule.xml
../app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/pmodule.xml
../app/design/frontend/default/default/template/company/module/gmap.phtml
../app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml
../app/locale/de_DE/Company_Module.csv
../app/locale/en_US/Company_Module.csv
../app/locale/fr_FR/Company_Module.csv
../skin/frontend/default/default/module/css/module.css
../skin/frontend/default/default/module/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
../skin/frontend/default/default/module/js/module.js
../skin/frontend/default/default/module/js/module_bak_20-05-2016.js
../skin/frontend/default/default/module/js/module_bak_21052016.js
```

Now I know `cp --parents` can copy the file along with it's parent directories and re-create structure if necessary, but how can I change directory just by passing `../` to the `cp` command, so that it picks up file from parent folder and not look for it in current folder ?

Comment: Is the directory structure same in your destination? Or the script should make it?

Comment: Script should make it, so no extra effort needed.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. What arguments do you want to pass to the script, and where should it copy the file? And please give your question a meaningful title: why on earth would you want to change directory without using the command whose job is precisely to do that?

Comment: I think I have explained my question pretty clear, I just need to copy specific files from my website root directory (Magento website) to another directory. These specific files I have listed out in a text file. So I want to copy those files along with the directory structure they are residing in, What's so complicated or not clear in that ?

Comment: @VickyDev Well, that's not what the original post says. Maybe, `tar`, `cpio` or `rsync` might be a better choice for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes but that's why I have asked question. I didn't know about either of the methods you said, also no answer is there depicting this and their documentations are too confusing to read/follow and without any realtime examples.

Answer (score -1):

> how can I change directory just by passing ../ to the cp command

You can not pass a "change directory" argument (comparable to the `-C` option of `tar`, for example) to any version of `cp` I have ever seen. Earlier, I suggested simply doing a `cd` in the shell script, before issuing the `cp` command, but that was deemed unhelpful, too.

Comment: But that sounds like a not-so-smart work, I want to know if this could be done with cp itself, then how ?

Answer (score -1):

These are my assumption:

File structure in the original place:

```
..
├── app
│   ├── code
│   ├── design
│   ├── etc
│   └── locale
│   └── ...
├── script.d
│   ├── file.list
│   ├── script.sh
└── skin
    └── frontend
    └── ...
```

**file.list** is the name of the file containing the list of files to be copied. **script.sh** is the following script.

```
#! /bin/bash

distDir="THE NEW DIRECTORY PATH" # <<<<<< Alter this line

for filePath in $(cat "file.list");
do
    len=$(wc -c "$filePath")
    newFilePath=$(cut -c4-$len "$filePath")

    tempFileName=$(grep -Po '[^/]+$' "$filePath")

    path=$(grep -Po '^.*/' "$newFilePath")

    newPath=$distDir

    for dir in $(echo "$path" | tr / '\n');
    do

        if [ $(ls "$newPath" | grep -P '^'$dir'$' | wc -l) = 0 ]
        then
            mkdir "$newPath"'/'"$dir"
            newPath="$newPath"'/'"$dir"
        fi

    done

    cp "$filePath" "$newPath"'/'
done
```

Just make sure you give the correct path in the first line.

Comment: so no need to change file.list, keep it as in my question, right ?

Comment: But my `destDir` is outside the folder of the script.

Comment: Keep file.list as it is. But add the path (you can give relative or absolute path like `~/blah/destination` for destDir)

Comment: I will check this on Monday, as I have Ubuntu in my office system.

Comment: All your uses of unquoted variable expansions, `echo | …`, etc. cause your script to be needlessly complicated, break on file names containing spaces and wildcard characters, and be slow. As *minimum* hygiene, use double quotes around variable substitutions, and use shell constructs (e.g. `${#filePath}` for the length of the value of a variable) instead of external tools.

Comment: Thank you @Gilles for your advises. I am new to shell script. I just replicated the file structure on my system (with another script) and checked this script on my system for several times to make sure it works perfectly. But I have to keep your advise in mind for future scripts to make sure it wont break. Thanks again